# Changing Color Of TextView text in android using spannableString

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a String

```
1 Friend | O Reviews | 0 Coupons
```

I am using following code

```
SpannableString hashText = new SpannableString(TextUtils.concat(
                friendsText,
                " | ",
                reviewsText,
                " | ",
                couponsText
        ).toString());

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\s* | \\s*").matcher(hashText);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            hashText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
        }

        detailsText.setText(hashText);
```

I want to change the color of | to blue from TextView original gray color.
Above code is doing nothing. What wrong am i doing in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
String text = TextUtils.join(" | ", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1 Friend", "1 Review", "1 Coupons"}));

        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text);

        int index = text.indexOf('|');
        while (index >= 0) {
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), index, index + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            index = text.indexOf('|', index + 1);
        }
        detailsText.setText(hashText);
```

OutPut:

[image]

Comment: " | " is placed at multiple places, it does work for 1 | but for wherever in the string

Comment: @MuhammadUmar it works for where ever it found '|'. Please run and see the output. I added screen shots for the same.

Comment: A pretty good example of spans can be seen [here](https://medium.com/@joseph.neeraj/android-spannable-string-example-864d4e7193bf)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text);

int index = text.indexOf(“|”);

while ( index >= 0) {
    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), index, index + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    index = text.indexOf(“|”, index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even here is accepted answer but i want share simplest method for users.

```
public void setHighLightedText(TextView tv, String textToHighlight) {
    String tvt = tv.getText().toString();
    int ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, 0);
    Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(tv.getText());

    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {
        ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, ofs);
        if (ofe == -1)
            break;
        else {
            // you can change or add more span as per your need
            wordToSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), ofe,ofe + textToHighlight.length(), 0); // set size
            wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), ofe, ofe + textToHighlight.length(), 0);// set color
            tv.setText(wordToSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Call this method like

```
textView.setText("1 Friend | O Reviews | 0 Coupons");
setHighLightedText(textView,"|");
```